# Toolbar disappearing when using TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an activity with some fragments which has a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. In an specific fragment, I want the toolbar to show a `TabLayout`. I have made it work.. well almost.

When changing to the fragment where `TabLayout` must be shown, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed using:

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpanded(false,true);
```

And the tabs are shown using this in the fragment code:

```
tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The issue is that the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is completely hidden and it only shows the tab bar, instead of the collapsed toolbar above the app bar.

This is the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
            android:transitionName="actionBar"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/toolbar_contentInset"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tabs_contentInset"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/tabs_contentInset"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/semitransparent_white"
            tools:ignore="NewApi,RtlSymmetry,UnusedAttribute"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And this is how it currently looks like, (and which I don't want it to be).

[image]

And this is how I expect/want it to look like:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you adding the Toolbar in your Activity? `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="24dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
        android:transitionName="actionBar"
        app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/toolbar_contentInset"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tabs_contentInset"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/tabs_contentInset"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/semitransparent_white"
        tools:ignore="NewApi,RtlSymmetry,UnusedAttribute"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

please tell me if it works or not in a comment

Good luck

Comment: hi, i was wandering if the answer provided was helpful, if yes , please close it by putting it as resolved, if no, leave a comment so we could help you more, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hello remove the next code line

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answer to this problem in here = https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817940/4258880.
But you can add an offset change listener to explicitly set your action bar when you reach a greater than percentage. (Sometimes I dont know why, the offset changes on scroll behavior, even though it has a fixed height)

**In Kotlin:**

```
app_bar_layout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
        val percentage: Float = Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()
        Log.d("%", "$percentage")
        when {
            percentage < 0.1 ->  (activity as MainActivity).bottom_navigation.visibility = View.GONE
            percentage >= 1.0.toFloat() -> (activity as MainActivity).setSupportActionBar(where_toolbar) // This is hack to avoid toolbar disappearing
            else ->  (activity as MainActivity).bottom_navigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
    })
```

Here I am using it to inflate it in a Fragment when the percetange is greater than 1 (Weird).